# Why ping unknown host is happening when inside a while loop?

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to get a column from a csv file and ping each line in a while loop
But every time it just show ping:unknown host (website)

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=, read num ip; do
   echo $num
   ping -c 10 $ip
done <site.csv
```

And the format of the csv file is

```
1, facebook.com
2, google.com
```

And the result will always be

```
ping: unknown host facebook.com
ping: unknown host google.com
```

But when I just ping the website directly, it is actually working, so i think is not the network problem

```
-bash-4.1$ ping -c 2 facebook.com
PING facebook.com (173.252.120.6) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from edge-star-shv-12-frc3.facebook.com (173.252.120.6): icmp_seq=1 ttl=70 time=94.1 ms
64 bytes from edge-star-shv-12-frc3.facebook.com (173.252.120.6): icmp_seq=2 ttl=70 time=93.8 ms

--- facebook.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1094ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 93.882/94.040/94.199/0.345 ms
```

Is it the while loop or read the column from the csv causing the prooblem?

Is there a way to use a wile loop to read the site from the csv file and ping it?

Comment: I tried with your script and your csv file and it works well. Are you showing us everything?

Comment: I bet your csv file has DOS-style line endings, so $ip is actually `facebook.com\r`

Comment: @glennjackman That would definitely explain it all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on Glenn Jackman's suggestion that the problem is DOS line-endings, here is a simple way to make sure that they are removed from the input.  Replace:

```
while IFS=, read num ip; do
```

With:

```
while IFS=$',\r' read num ip; do
```

By adding `\r` to `IFS`, this makes the shell treat the DOS character as a field separator.  This means it does not become part of `ip`.